# i have error in socket.io with node and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

```
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  
  console.log('a user connected');
  
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{
        const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
        setSocket(socket);
        console.log(socket);
},[]);
```

[image]

can anyone know what's the problem please

i tried to connect node and react with socket.io to do chat online realtime but i always get this problem

Comment: Can you upload all the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.